# Unable to import RestBuilder to Grails 2.4.5 project

Tags: rest, grails, plugins, grails-2.0

We are using Grails 2.4.5 and are trying to use the RestBuilder class to implement some functional tests for our REST API's.
I have included compile "org.grails.plugins:rest-client-builder:2.1.1" in the BuildConfig.groovy file.
I can see that the plugin is downloaded but do not see the RestBuilder class in any src directory. I also do not see any references to other dependencies that might include RestBuilder.

Could this be an issue when the plugin was upgraded/moved for Grails 3.x?
Thanks,
Kathy

Answer (score 2):

> Could this be an issue when the plugin was upgraded/moved for Grails
>   3.x?

No.

You are expressing a dependency on `org.grails.plugins:rest-client-builder:2.1.1` which depends on `org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:3.1.4.RELEASE` and that is where `grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder` is coming from. You should see the corresponding jar file under your home directory in `/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails/grails-datastore-rest-client/jars/grails-datastore-rest-client-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar`.

Comment: The dependency from `rest-client-builder` to `grails-datastore-rest-client` is expressed at https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-rest-client-builder/blob/2f568501aed5cee02dbef08b184dd53b35a5d36f/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy#L21

Comment: For the benefit of others who find this question later, I had an exchange with the original asker in our Slack channel and the problem turned out to just be a problem with her IDE.  The class otherwise is available as expected.